# Why posts on a public Facebook page are not public?

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a public Facebook page. However the posts (longer than the short ones) on the page cannot be displayed by unsigned users.

A few of the posts (first ones) can be extended using the link *See More*.
Other posts have a link *Continue Reading* and do not allow a unsigned user to read them unless he sign in. I do not see any difference in setting of the posts. What is the matter? Can I somehow fix that?

The page is https://www.facebook.com/cilicile

Answer (score 2):

This might be a reason of restrictions on your page you have set in settings.
If your page has restrictions, then the user will need to be logged in to view your page.

Adjust page settings:

- Login to Facebook
- Go to your page
- Click **Edit Page**
- Click **Manage Permissions** on the left hand side.

**Country Restrictions:** If you have a restriction, your page will not be public. Someone must be logged in, in order to view your page.

**Age Restriction:** If you have a restriction, your page will not be public. Someone must be logged in, in order to view your page.

**Moderation Blacklist:** If there is anything written in that box, your page will not be public. Someone must be logged in, in order to view your page.

**Profanity Blacklist:**  If you have selected an option other than **none** your page will not be public. Someone must be logged in, in order to view your page.

Here is an image for reference:

[image]

Image source: Internet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but all this I have selected as indicated. Can there be another problem?